# Creating JSON API inside existing Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having Rails web-app that has a form that pushes a request of a certain document into DB. A script on other machine should ask for newly created request. To handle that I've diced to add small JSON API inside the app.

For that purpose in routes I've added

```
  defaults format: :json do
    get "/api_name/get_request", to: "api_name#get_request"
  end
```

After that I've met CSRF problem. And after googling I've found out that I need to add `protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }` in my controller. It looks like the code as follows

```
class ApiNameController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }

  def get_request
    render json: {message: 'Received'}, status: :ok
  end
end
```

After that in log I have

```
Started GET "/api_name/get_request" for ::1 at 2018-02-05 16:43:08 +0300
Processing by ApiNameController#get_request as JSON
  Parameters: {"api_name"=>{}}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

So the problem is still there. The questions are

1. What should I do to solve the problem?
2. Allowing JSON requests from any origin seem to be dangerous. How can I ad some protection? Maybe I should send some header from remote machine and check it inside `verified_request` ?

**UPD** I've changed comment inside `get_request` with `render json: {message: 'Received'}, status: :ok` and after that the result is the same

Comment: what do u have in `application_cntr..`?

Comment: This is a 401 response, which suggests a different error. In my apps CSRF errors return 422 status. Are you using Devise or another authentication system? Also, have you tried boosting your log level to *debug*

Comment: @Phil, yes I have `before_action :authenticate_user!, :unless => :devise_controller?` in app controller

Comment: if u need an authentication actions, let me know i can update the post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to skip devise before_actions, if its assigned in ApplicationController.

**Controllers:**

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
   protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? }
   skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :get_request

   def get_request
      render json: {message: 'Received'}, status: :ok
   end

end
```

**Routes:**

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
   get 'get_request' => 'api#get_request'
end
```

To handle cross origin:

[Rack Cors Gem Link](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)

[Rack Attack Gem Link](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack)

Answer (score 1):

You probaly have some web authentication in `ApplicationController` in `before_filter`, since your `ApiNameController` inherits from it. That's why you receive `Unauthorized` response. So you should either stop inheriting from it, or exclude api controller methods from web-auth before-hook with some sort of:

```
class ApiNameController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :get_request
```

Speaking of security, you have at least two options:

- [token-based authentication](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/token-based-authentication-with-ruby-on-rails-5-api)
- [basic auth](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html)

The last one is less secure than token-based auth, but it's easier to implement, so it's up to you which one to chose.